# Scipy ndimage filters unusable with large kernels

Tags: python, scipy

There seems to be a practical limit to the size of a kernel in ndimage filters. For example, the following snippet requires 3GB of memory..

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

L = 2000
kern = 140

img = np.random.rand(L * L).reshape(L, L)
filtered = ndimage.median_filter(img, size=kern)
```

There must be a lot of caching happening as the kernel moves across the image.

I'd like to use a `generic_filter` function with a circular footprint of radius approx. 200 pixels, however I don't have nearly enough memory to consider that feasible.

Is there a way to control the caching behaviour of the scipy filter functions (if that's indeed what's happening) to allow using large kernels?

Comment: What do you need such a big filter for? Why can't you resample and use a smaller one?

Comment: I may well be able to. The custom generic filter is complex, involving a histogram under the footprint, so the amount I can safely downsample isn't obvious. There's nothing particularly evil about filtering with a large kernel, is there?

Comment: FYI I'm making a continuous map of [number density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_density). Objects have unique labels, and I use a histogram under the footprint combined with information about the labels total size to weight the count when there is partial coverage.

Comment: Well, a 5x5-filter would process 99 Megapixels, 5*5*(2000-5)*(2000-5), whereas your 200x200-filter would have to process 200*200*(2000-200)*(2000-200) = 129 Gigapixels. Not sure whether that already warrants being labeled "evil", but I think it comes close.

Comment: There'll be huge resource requirements for sure, but is it not an issue of finding a balance between memory consumption and execution time?

Comment: Would a more sensible question be asking about a specific algorithm for computing the "continuous map of number density"?

Comment: I don't think Stackoverflow would be the right place to ask for an algorithm. Maybe try scicomp or one of the other stackexchange pages. Also, check out integral images, maybe the they would be helpful to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks - the countable objects vary in size, which needs to be _not_ reflected in the data. I don't think that'd be the case with an integral. I think this question is still valid though.